# Exceptions: maximum message size

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, exception

I've got a bug that is hard to reproduce. Also, I'm told that writing log files is a security liability. So I want to capture as much as I can in an exception.

I can't find any place that says what a maximum length is for C# exceptions.

I'd like to stick an XML message (1 or 2K) and maybe my local data model (2k or so).

What are the limits? Any best practice advice?

Comment: Throw an exception and see if you can write out the XML message and local data model

Comment: .NET limitations on object sizes is 2 gigabytes or the maximum amount of contiguous virtual memory available, which ever is lowest.  So an Exception.Message string with a billion characters is possible.

Answer (score 5):

Better to use Trace.Information, Trace.Error since it is available in production.

I suppose if you were not in production Debug.Write or Console.Write would be your best bet.

As for max exception message length it is max string length (Int32.MaxValue or 2,147,483,647).

Here is my test harness:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string _loremIpsum = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

long _counter = 5000;
while (_counter > 0)
{
    sb.Append(_loremIpsum);
    if (_counter % 100 == 0)
    {
        Console.Write(".");
    }
    _counter--;
}
Console.WriteLine("Length: " + sb.Length);

throw new Exception(sb.ToString());
```

I should note putting looong strings into an exception really slows things down, but it isn't too bad.

Reference for how long a string can be [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/149251/Debugging-Tracing-and-Instrumentation-in-NET-and-A).